# Multithreading issue,Error: <identifier> expected

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class TaskThread
{

  String temp=infoGenerator();

  String arr[]=str.split(" ",3);

  Runnable customer1=new Customer(parseInt(arr[0]),arr[1],arr[2]);//create first customer


  String temp=infoGenerator();

  String arr[]=str.split(" ",3);

  Runnable customer2=new Customer(parseInt(arr[0]),arr[1],arr[2]);//creates second customer


  String temp=infoGenerator();

  String arr[]=str.split(" ",3);

  Runnable customer3=new Customer(parseInt(arr[0]),arr[1],arr[2]);//creates third customer


  Thread thread1=new Thread(customer1);//adds customers to their own thread

  Thread thread2=new Thread(customer2);

  Thread thread3=new Thread(customer3);


  thread1.start();

  thread2.start();

  thread3.start();
```

//Sorry for not explaining issue, 
I have attempted to use multithreading to create multiple Customer objects which then use the `overriden run()` method to do perform expected outcome. The compiler specifies that the issue is in all three lines using the `start()` method, it provides the error message:Error:  expected.

Comment: Please explain the problem, simply posting the code will not help others to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You dont explain what you are trying to achieve so it is harder to help you, but the compilation error seems to be because you are trying to write the code

```
  thread1.start();

  thread2.start();

  thread3.start();
```

simply inside the class `TaskThread`, but not in a method. you can declare variables inside classes, but for codes and functionality, you need methods and functions, like this:

```
public class TaskThread
{
    // here declare your variables...

    public void doSomething() {
          thread1.start();
          thread2.start();
          thread3.start();    
    }
}
```